# Hotkeys guide for Firefox 4?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys, firefox

Is there a guide to keyboard shortcuts for Firefox 4? I am wondering if most Firefox functions, like bookmarking and switching between tabs, can be controlled from the keyboard.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page is accessible from the help menu in Firefox if you search for "shortcuts".](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts?s=shortcuts&as=s)

> This is a list of keyboard shortcuts in Mozilla Firefox. If you have enabled Emacs-style text editing shortcuts in GNOME, they will also work in Firefox. When an Emacs text editing shortcut conflicts with the default shortcuts (as occurs with Ctrl+K), the Emacs shortcut will take preference if focus is inside a text box (which would include the location bar and search bar). In such cases you should use the alternate keyboard shortcut if one is listed below.
>
> Firefox does not provide any method of customizing keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Of course!

Mozilla has a [**fairly detailed**](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts) list of documented keyboard shortcuts. Most shortcuts from Firefox 3.x have carried over to Firefox 4.

Personally, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + the tab number to switch between tabs if there aren't very many. To bookmark a page, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is what you want. It works on almost all other browsers as well for the same purpose.