# Mouse like scrolling with keyboard in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, scrolling

As a followup to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/284286/hotkeys-guide-for-Firefox-4), I've trying the ways to move through a webpage with the keyboard in Firefox 6.

However, there seems to be no way to do smooth, fine scale scrolling with the keyboard. Every time I hit one of the movement hot keys, the page either jumps down a page (I.e. w/ Page Down), or jumps to the next item/link (which may be in the same view, or jumps to a whole other section of the page).

Is there a way to achieve the same scrolling you get with the mouse in Firefox 6+?

Comment: I don't have this problem. The scrowling is available with the mouse or the keyboard arrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the Firefox addon [Yet Another Smooth Scrolling](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yet-another-smooth-scrolling/).

[image]

Comment: This is a must-have addon for me.

Comment: Awesome addon, thanks for sharing it!! Works great.

Answer (score 3):

Use your arrow keys for keyboard scrolling.

Comment: @Dsandre Yes, but my view jumps instead of scroll...

Comment: @Penyuan Is it the case on every web pages ?

Comment: If that's happening I'd look into a plugin possibly causing it, default behavior is to scroll smoothly using arrow keys.

Comment: Keyboard scrolling is an option.

Answer (score 0):

(Short of using a smooth-scrolling plugin, which I have not tried), I find that, if you are using your cursor to follow where you are on the page (`CTRL-right_arrow`, `CTRL-left_arrow' to jump to next/previous word;` up-arrow`, down-arrow` to move up/down a line), then pressing `pagedown, pageup` will move the screen down one page, and then put your cursor back where it was.

Assuming you are navigating this way with the keyboard the above operation is necessary because pagedown on its own moves the cursor down a page as it moves the screen a page up, leaving your cursor a whole page away from where you were reading.

This doesn't work if you are in an edit box, such as the one StackExchange provides for answering questions. You still have to reach for the mouse when you find the edit box has disappeared off the bottom of the page (as it always does) and you want to move to the text that is down there, as though anyone who writes in edit boxes on webpages only ever do so in stream-of-consciousness, and never edit what they write, so their cursor is always at the bottom of the text.

I do not know either any way of jumping paragraphs. There is none given in the [default Firefox keybindings](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly).

And navigating text this way (though essential) can get extremely frustrating until you train yourself out of good habits, because `right-arrow`, `left-arrow`, on their own, will cause Firefox to navigate off the page you are on and onto the next/previous webpage.

In all, the Firefox keybindings have evolved about as much as has a lump of coal which I happened to have had for about a decade (it sits on my shelf, for good reasons I won't explain here). They are clearly not designed for people who want to work efficiently with their keyboard, and might be making use of those of those excellent plugins that interact with the page.

Firefox provides the facility to navigate links and pages in a rudimentary fashion, as though the web where made entirely of lumps of brick with photographs of text pasted on them. It's like Firefox folk work with the intent of providing the world with a means of reading pages taken from a printing press, through a cheap telescope. You can move the viewfinder, change the focus and flip the page. But the field of view is narrow, and while you can flip your eye from word and line, to get to the next paragraph or scan down the page, you have to move the telescope and that simply makes the image jump. So unless you are the patient sort who is prepared to make the best of the inadequate tools he(/she/heshe/shehe/other) has, you may soon find you have thrown your telescope through the window and burned all the books.

This is particularly evident if you ever try to navigate the links on the results page of a Google search. Even simply navigating links with the keyboard is rubbish, and that is, by all other appearances, the purpose Firefox was designed to address.

What it really needs is some good vim keybindings plugin. I did try one or two a few years ago, very briefly. It is long overdue I tried those again. The Firefox keyboard help page (linked above) says that in limited circumstances you can use Emacs-style bindings. That's just spiteful.